# angular expressions not being evaluated by browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, phpstorm

I am using Angular in PHP.  I have copied the angular.js file to the project and reference it.  Below is my project:  (yes it is from the CodeSchool tutorial).

Index.html (html5)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="store" >
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/vendors/Twitter/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/vendors/Angular/angular.js"></script>
    <title>Flatlanders Gems</title>
</head>
<body >

    <div ng-controller="storeController">
            <h1> {{storeController.product.name}} </h1>
            <h2> {{storeController.product.price}} </h2>
            <p> {{storeController.product.description}} </p>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

and my app.js

```
(function () {
    var ap = angular.module('store', []);
    app.controller('storeController', function () {
        this.product = gem;
    });
    var gem = {
        name:'Dodecahedron',
        price: 2.95,
        description: '...'
    }
})();
```

Code completion works in phpStorm.  Interestingly, storeController does not display product, but product does display the name price and description elements

here is my directory structure:
[image]
when I run the app either from php or directy in the browser (using xamp) I get the following:

and here is my output
[image]

I get the same results whether I use Angular 1.4 or 1.5

It appears that it is not seeing either the app.js or the angular.js (or is there something else missing?)  I have tried with the references beginning with: 
    /dist 
    ./dist and 
    ~/dist 
all with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the `variable name` of your module in `app.js file`. You put `ap` but when use `app` to create your controller.

```
var ap = angular.module('store', []);
app.controller('storeController', function () {
    this.product = gem;
});
```

instead of

```
var app = angular.module('store', []);
app.controller('storeController', function () {
    this.product = gem;
});
```

or

```
var ap = angular.module('store', []);
ap.controller('storeController', function () {
    this.product = gem;
});
```

So correct your var name and it will work.

Comment: I had another error:  I was missing the () at the end of my anonymous function.  

That is the last line of app.js should be

}) ();

Thanks to all of you for the very fast response.  I think everyone (except me) noticed the typo on the module definition.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you named the controller `storeController` and then used it to prefix your bound model `product`.  Your model object is `product`, which is instantiated in your `storeController` controller.  It should look like this:

```
<div ng-controller="storeController">
    <h1> {{product.name}} </h1>
    <h2> {{product.price}} </h2>
    <p>  {{product.description}} </p>
</div>
```

And in your javascript...

```
var app = angular.module('store', []);
app.controller('storeController', function () {

var gem = {
    name:'Dodecahedron',
    price: 2.95,
    description: '...'
}

this.product = gem;
});
```

You want to instantiate 'gem' before you assign it to your scope, or better yet just assign it right to `$scope.products`.

```
$scope.product = {
    name:'Dodecahedron',
    price: 2.95,
    description: '...'
}
```

Also, there is a type in your `var app = angular...`

I don't believe this entire thing needs to be wrapped in an anonymous function.

**EDIT** It is actually good practice to wrap as Shitsu mentioned.

Comment: the wrapping is indeed a good practice, check out https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Answer (score 2):

is angular loading properly, did you get any errors in the console

`var ap = angular.module('store', []);
    app.controller('storeController', function () {`

it looks like that you have a typo, it should be app in both cases

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is a syntax error: `var ap` should be `var app` in your js file.

Also, if you don't use `$scope`, you have to use the "controller as" syntax, i.e. in your html, write:

```
<div ng-controller="storeController as ctrl">
       <h1> {{ctrl.product.name}} </h1>
       <h2> {{ctrl.product.price}} </h2>
       <p> {{ctrl.product.description}} </p>
</div>
```

If there are errors in your angular module, nothing will work. Try to fix it and check the logs in your console (press F12 in chrome or firefox), normally angular is kind of verbose.

The `gem` problem mentionned by @Tuesdave is a good point, but your wrapping in an anonymous function is a good point, so keep it !